# Short story about road rage arms race

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

I read a short story at least 20 years ago, in which a man gets news that his son was killed on the highway while driving a starter car and responds by getting into his own tricked out car to duel the guy who killed the son. Dad was some kind of ace, IIRC. I thought it was by Norman Spinrad, but I've been looking for it and can't seem to find it.

Comment: From that summary, it certainly sounds like Spinrad.

Comment: What is a starter car?

Comment: Well, in today's world, a starter car would be an older car that won't be expensive to fix or replace if the teen wrecks. In this story, it's the same, but also lightly armed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Why Johnny Can't Speed" by Alan Dean Foster.  It's in a collection named "With Friends Like These" (1984).

Weaponized cars fighting on the freeways of SoCal in a dystopian future.
Kill flags stamped on the side of the car a la WW2 fighter planes.
Offensive driving is the best defensive driving.

Now I want to reread it.

Comment: The story is available at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v32n02_1971-09).