Short science fiction story about "Full Contact Football"
I'm trying to identify a short story about "Full Contact Football". I think I read it in the 60's or 70's. The teams were based on ethnicity rather than regional. One of them was something like "Golden Supermen".

If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] in newly realized details, e.g. "I'm sure it isn't Full Frontal Footie because there couldn't have been a Soviet team because the entirety of the USSR had been taken over by McDonalds and Taco Bell, and I'm certain that the romance story involved two male reporters from North and South Dakota finding common ground."

Could this be The National Pastime By Norman Spinrad?

Various teams play "combat football!!!".


Yeah, yeah, Combat football, or better, Combat football. Two standard
football teams, standard football field, standard football rules,
except: Take off all their pads and helmets and jerseys and make it a
warm-weather game that they play in shorts and sneakers, like boxing.
More meaningful, more intimate violence. Violence is what sells
football, so give ’em a bit more violence than football, and you’ll
draw a bit more than football. The more violent you can make it and
get away with it, the better you’ll draw.
Yeah... and you could get away with punching; after all, boxers belt
each other around and they still allow boxing on television; sports
have too much All-American Clean for the antiviolence freaks to
attack; in fact, where their heads are at, they’d dig Combat football.


Teams include the "Golden Supermen".


Buoyed by the success of their fans, the Hogs on the field recovered
the ball on their own twenty-nine with less than two minutes to play
when Chain-Mail Dixon belted Tex McGhee into a fumble and out of the
game.
The Hogs crunched their way upfield yard by yard, punch by punch,
against a suddenly shaky Supermen opposition, and, all at once, the
whole season came down to one play: with the score 17-14 and twenty
seconds left on the clock, time enough for one or possibly two more
plays, the Hogs had the ball third and four on the eighteen-yard line
of the Golden Supermen.


So, rugby then.

@DoscoJones - "...a sport for gentlemen played by hooligans"

If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/173749/23243

Anthologized more times than I might have guessed:  https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58111

@DoscoJones "a game played by men with odd-shaped balls"

@DoscoJones until now I thought there were only two different games called "football".  Learn something new every day!
